# Github Api, fetching user email

Tags: api, github, request, axios

I would like to make a simple api GET request to get user email based on account name/username. 
I am using axios and when I make GET request using this `https://api.github.com/users/[username]` 
I get back everything I need(repository, followers...) except for the user email. It is always null. It would be enough for me to get just the email from users that set it as a public on their profile but no matter what it is set to it will always return null. I am reading that maybe I need authorisation. I made personal Access Token on my github account but how would I use it? What si the best way to get user email?

This is what I have now

```
import axios from 'axios'

const REQUEST = 'https://api.github.com/users/'


module.exports = {
  getData: (accountName) => {
    const encodedAccountName = encodeURIComponent(accountName)
    const requestUrl = `${REQUEST}${encodedAccountName}`

    return axios.get(requestUrl).then((res) => {
      return res
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I managed to get this working like this. I simply send a header with personalAccessToken together with request. You can get personal access token on github page under settings/Personal access token/Generate new token and choose user:email for scope. It would be good to use ENV variable now for access token.

```
import axios from 'axios'

const REQUEST = 'https://api.github.com/users/'

var config = {
  headers: {'Authorization': 'token 847762643...'}
}

module.exports = {
  getData: (accountName) => {
    const encodedAccountName = encodeURIComponent(accountName)
    const requestUrl = `${REQUEST}${encodedAccountName}`

    return axios.get(requestUrl, config).then(res => {
      return res
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [`Requestable.js`](http://github-tools.github.io/github/docs/1.2.1/Requestable.js.html) object from [GitHub.js tool](http://github-tools.github.io/github/)

It does define the AuthorizationHeader based on a token:

```js
  this.__apiBase = apiBase || 'https://api.github.com';
  this.__auth = {
     token: auth.token,
     username: auth.username,
     password: auth.password
  };
  if (auth.token) {
     this.__authorizationHeader = 'token ' + auth.token;
  } else if (auth.username && auth.password) {
     this.__authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode(auth.username + ':' + auth.password);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks VonC. I will investigate this way also but for now you can see my answer how I managed to get it working, although OAuth would be better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get user email from GitHub API using below code.

```
https://api.github.com/user/emails?access_token=${token}
```

Comment: It's deprecated to use query parameters: https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-10-deprecating-auth-through-query-param/